# Android studio, How to upload image to server from external URL?

Tags: java, android, image-uploading

I'm working on google authentication, I have the account picture URL and I need to upload this picture to my server. Is there any solution to directly transfer the picture from Google URL to server instead of going through the phone ?

Sorry for my english and thank you for your help.

Comment: why you need to transfer if it already on google? If you really want to then give url to the server and it will download the image from google